# Export data to a file with row indices added

Tags: export, printing

While `Export["file.txt", A, "Table"]` exports a file of data, A represents a data set, in column form the question is about how to export, or print, a set of data with each data point being numbered. As an example consider the recurrence relation `a[n+1]== 2*a[n]+1, a[0]=0` which yields the set of data `{1, 1, 3, 7, ...}`. Now if the data is exported to a file it looks like

`1
 1
 3
 7`

What this question is about is how to have the data set exported to a file such that it reads:

`0 1
 1 1
 2 3
 3 7`

where the first column is the `n` value of the recurrence relation and the second column is the corresponding data value. As an additional consideration can this two column output be applied to numerical values ? For an example consider the value of Pi calculated by `N[Pi, 200]`. Can the exported file have an output of the form

`0 3
 1 1
 2 4
 3 ...`   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myA = Transpose[{Range[Length[x]], x}]

Export["file.txt", myA, "Table"]
```

Incidentally, never use an upper-case letter or name beginning with an upper-case letter for your lists, variables or functions, to avoid potential naming conflicts with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

```
myA = Transpose[{Range[200], RealDigits[N[π, 200]][[1]]}]
```